SpringBoot Functional Endpoints in Servlet stack, correct way to write to ServerResponse's outputStream
Trying to write a stream directly  to the ServerResponse's of a functional endpoint, but unfortunately it does not work.
with the below way.
    ServerResponse getResponse (inputRequest){
      StreamingResponseBody stream = (OutputStream outputStream) -> {
            try {
                item.visit(JsonEncoder(outputStream));
                println("Streaming ended");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
        return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(stream)
    }

but the lambda is never called in the ServerResponse return way. Is any other way of writing directly in outputBuffer of ServerResponse(immutable object)?
